# file_field is not sticky in my Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a pretty standard Rails form:

```
<div>
    <h1>Create a New Listing</h1>
    <%- form_for @listing, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| -%>
                    <div><%= f.label :title, "Title:"%> <%= f.text_field :title %></div>
            <div>
                <%= f.label :image, "Image:" %> <%= f.file_field :image 
            </div>
            <div>
                <%= f.label :sound, "Sound Clip:"%> <%= f.file_field :sound %><br />
            </div>
        <div class="submit"><%= f.submit 'Post Listing' %></div>
    <%- end -%>
</div>
```

When a user chooses a file, but the form fails for validation purposes, he must always re-select the file.  It is not sticky.  Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make the file field sticky, I think. Even if Rails provides the initial value, most browsers will just ignore it (or otherwise, some smart-aleck could set the default file to `/etc/passwd`, and if you don't pay attention, next thing you know your box is rooted.

The best you can do that I can think of is set a flag that says a file has already been uploaded, so if the user does not select another one, use the one already sent in the last request.

**UPDATE:** You'd be surprised how many people have no security skills whatsoever. I've known people to use a browser as `root`. However, "why" is not exactly an issue - the important point I was trying to make is just that it's not Rails's fault, the problem most likely lies in the browser behaviour.

You can read [an article](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html) that says it better than I can...

**UPDATE 2:** "Your box is rooted" should say "the user's box is rooted". The scenario I describe is this: User submits a file `innocent.txt` and a CAPTCHA. Malicious server responds CAPTCHA is wrong, enter it again, and *covertly changes the file from `innocent.txt` to `~/.ssh/id_rsa`*. User does not look at the file field (he already put in the correct value there), so just redoes the CAPTCHA and pushes submit. Now the server has the user's private SSH key.

Comment: "some smart-aleck could set the default file to /etc/passwd" ...wouldn't the web server need to have root access to do that?  I don't provide that security hole.

Comment: also, how would that be different than the user just doing that anyway...with a POST request to my app?  seems like this issue is separate from stickiness

Comment: The difference is that if user does it, it is directly the person's responsibility. If the page "tricks" a person to upload something he wouldn't want to upload (okay, maybe `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is a better example that `/etc/passwd`), sure, the person could pay more attention, but I'd blame the web page.

Comment: Basically, the same difference between a person giving his credit card to his spendthrifty wife, and getting it stolen from his pocket in the train. In the first case, it's his own fault. In the second, he could have paid attention, but I'd blame the pickpocket.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed where we misunderstood each other. By "your box is rooted" I actually meant the impersonal "yours" - i.e. the user's (not your server).